# Scary book series from the 1990's, short stories and came in hardcover?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, childrens-novel

I'm looking for a book series I owned a few books of in my childhood, they were compilation novels and I recall they had about three stories or so in each one. One of the stories I remember vividly was about a town where kids keep going missing (and ending up on milk cartons) and it's because of a blob that lives in the sewers. Unfortunately that's the only one I can recall off the top of my head but I remember another one of the books had a cover with an image of an evil looking dog that was black and red. I don't know if they came in paperback, but the only ones I had were all hardcover (if that helps at all)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: These sound like Dean Koontz stories - "Phantoms" and "Watchers," I believe, from your descriptions. But those are both standalone novels...